# Salesforce Permission Set Access

Tags: salesforce, permissionset

I have already an object without any access on it. Only System Administrator has access on its fields.

I had a permission set to grant access to this object for some users (not a system admin). All permissions Read All, Modify All are granted to this object and its fields.

I create a new field on the same object and I gave the system administrator only the access to it. Then, I added access to it on the permission set.

I tried to connect with another user (assigned already to the permission set) and I tried to create a new record for this object or modify an existing record but the problem that the new field that I added recently did not appear on the page layout.

I search online and I did everything mentioned in the solutions even I tried to give access also to the profile of the user but even I couldn't see the new field.

Any solution please? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a lookup field and I needed to give access to the object itself too. So when I give the access to the object I could see the field on the Layout

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might already found an answer to this issue, if not did you make sure the newly created field is added to the page layout. If it is added to the page layout then atleast can you see with your admin access.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment and I know that you don't have enough privilege to put this in a comment, but all of us earned the privileges the hard way too. I am upvoting your answer to give you enough points so you can move this to a comment and delete this answer